# Do you need need to have an above average IQ in order to have a reasonable chance of successful career in STEM fields?

Tags: measurement

Particularly engineering, computer science, math. I came across [this quote from someone who specializes in psychometrics](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-scientifically-proven-if-hard-work-in-STEM-fields-can-compensate-for-a-medium-low-IQ) in response to this question.

> Is it scientifically proven if hard work in STEM fields can compensate for a medium/low IQ?

> "No.
>
> If by “low IQ” you mean a score of 80 or below, there are absolutely no compensatory mechanisms, including hard work, for STEM fields. A person at such an intellectual level is unlikely to finish the first year of college-level work in any academic disciple.
>
> IF, by “medium IQ,” you mean a full-scale score in the 90–110, it isn’t likely that compensatory mechanisms such as a high level of industriousness (hard work) will be advantageous. Exception being for those with exceptional working memory and an island of excellence for abstract/logical thinking in the higher end of average."

My question is whether or not this claim is true. If a person has average intelligence (an IQ of 100) and no "island of excellence", do they have very little chance of having a successful career in STEM no matter how hard they work?

Whether it's in engineering, computer science or obtaining a PhD in math, physics and so on? Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. It is best to link to the original text when quoting somebody. It acknowledges the person who originally said such things. Sometimes, it also provides more context. I have helped by doing that for you.

Comment: What do you mean with the 'island of excellence' you are talking about? The  'hard working' type, or a subskill within the IQ test? There are different types of intelligence being tested in a regular IQ test that ultimately get averaged.